# Why can't I use my newly created API key?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I had just now created  a new API key after enabling Places API in the developer console.

*Code for implementing Place picker API:*

```
 Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "@string/google_place_api");
    List<com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.Field> placeFields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.Field.values()));
                List<TypeFilter> typeFilters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(TypeFilter.values()));
// Create a RectangularBounds object.
                RectangularBounds bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(
                        new LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
                        new LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596));
                Intent autocompleteIntent =
                        new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, placeFields)
                                .setLocationBias(bounds)
                                .setTypeFilter(typeFilters.get(0))
                                .build(getApplicationContext());
                startActivityForResult(autocompleteIntent, 1001);




@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1001) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),place.getName()+ ", " + place.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status.getStatusMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is that I keep getting a toast showing **The provided API key is invalid** whenever I try to search for a location. How is this possible? The API key I got is completely new.

**Edit:** This is the error that I keep getting in my Logcat

```
The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
2019-04-29 19:36:10.285 14975-14975/com.example.myapplication E/Places: Error while autocompleting: REQUEST_DENIED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly passing the API Key.

Replace this line:

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "@string/google_place_api");
```

with:

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.google_place_api));
```